# Efficiently and Eloquently Inserting/Deleting/Updating Child Records

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have page a that shows a header record along with a list of detail records.  I'm struggling with making a clean and efficient way of inserting/deleting/updating detail records when the user clicks Save.

The detail records are shown in a jQuery DataTable, and the view model behind each detail record has an IsNew and IsRemoved property.  When the user adds a detail record, its IsNew property is set to true.  When the user removes a detail record, it is soft-deleted and its IsRemoved property is set to true.

When the user clicks Save and posts the page to my controller, my logic right now looks like this

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult EditData(ViewModel viewModel)
{
    // Update the record's header details here
    // ...

    foreach (var childViewModel in viewModel.Children)
    {
        // Use AutoMapper to map the view model to a model
        MyChildRecord childModel = this.mapper.Map<MyChildRecord>(childViewModel);

        if (childViewModel.IsNew)
        {
            this.context.MyChildRecords.Add(childModel);                
        }
        else if (childViewModel.IsRemoved)
        {
            this.context.MyChildRecords.Attach(childModel);
            this.context.MyChildRecords.Remove(childModel);
        }
        else
        {
            this.context.Entry(childModel).State = EntityState.Modified;
        }
    }

    this.context.SaveChanges();

    return RedirectToAction("EditData", new { id = viewModel.Id } );
}
```

The thing I don't like about this code is that even if nothing about a child record is changed, I'm still updating it in the database.  The only solutions I can come up with to prevent that are

1. Have each view model store a copy of its original values and then compare its current value to its original values when the user saves the page.  I don't like this solution because I'll have to have a bunch of code to store the original values, and then I have to put the original values as hidden fields on my ASP page so that they get carried between web requests.
2. When the user saves the page, have the controller iterate through each child view model, load the original data from the database, and compare the view model's current values to see if the row needs to be updated or not.  I don't like this method because it involves a lot of extra code for the field comparison, and I still have to make unncessary trips to the database.

This seems like a common scenario so there must be a commonly accepted way of doing this.  How should I be going about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, consider that while the extra updates do incur additional network traffic, the likelihood is that your actual database server is smart enough not to actually do anything to the database on disk if nothing changed.

Secondly, consider that your application might not be the only program working with your database table. Somebody else might have changed the record while you were looking at it.  To be safe, you really need both solutions together: check whether the user changed your form, AND check whether the database row is the same as it was when you got the data to show to the user.  If both have changed, usually it is considered an error and the user is notified.

Comment: How would you suggest I perform a field-by-field comparison?  I worry that writing a comparison of every field is very time consuming as the application grows and will also be bug-prone as additional fields are added to pre-existing classes because the programmer might forget to add them to the comparison method or forget to add them as hidden fields to the ASP page.  I could solve the manual comparison problem by making a comparison function using reflection, but the ASP hidden field problem is still there.  If that's the only way then so be it; I'm just hoping for something better.

Comment: The usual solution on the database side is to use an ORM framework, such as NHibernate, LINQ to SQL or Entity Framework from Microsoft, or something similar, and not work with SQL directly. Such frameworks will generate the voluminous and boring checking code automatically at compile time.

Comment: I'm not as much up on the UI side, but I believe MVC - Model-View-Controller - has related concepts that detect which fields changed on the postback.  Really it comes down to, you're doing too much yourself. Learn about the industry standard solutions and use them.

Comment: I'm using Entity Framework, but I'm not sure how that solves the problem about comparing all view model fields to the model fields, or solves the problem about having a bunch of hidden ASP fields on the page.  Won't I still have to have a bunch of checks like `if (viewModel.FirstName != model.FirstName || viewModel.LastName != model.LastName || ...`

Comment: I guess I'm both a poor reader of your question, and over my head. I apologize. Perhaps I should delete this Answer; you should definitely un-upvote it as it doesn't answer you.

Comment: No no, your answer was helpful.  It gives evidence that what I'm trying to do about wringing a bit of extra performance out of my application might get me into far more trouble than it's worth.  The few other posts that I've found about people trying to issue database updates only for fields that were changed tend to agree with you said that adding all this extra logic isn't worth it.  I'm going to leave the question unanswered for now in hopes that someone has a good solution for this, but your answer is helpful and hence the upvote.

Comment: If what I'm already doing is more-or-less the best solution, I'm fine with that.  I just don't want to do this badly if a better way exists.